# Check if an email has been sent to a user on the previous day

Tags: python, sql, database

I have a python script that when run it will automatically send an email to a user using python's smtplib  package. It runs on 2 conditions from a sql query,  if they have a new customer or if they havent spoken with their customer in a long time (sends a reminder to call them)  I could see our team requesting this check to be run on a daily basis, but what if a user already received an email? It would probably be annoying to get the same email over and over again.

I was wondering if theres someway that I can capture if a user was **sent**   an email or not? I am not sure what that would look like in python? I am thinking I probably will have to create some sort of a database that tracks when an email was sent or not, otherwise how would the program know if something was sent last run. The problem with the database solution is that I dont have the power to update tables (we depend on another department to manipulate our snowflake tables)

If anyone has any thoughts that would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Your title says "sent", but the question says "received". It's easier to tell when a message has been sent than when it has been received.

Comment: ah yah let me fix the wording. I do want to know when a message has been sent and somehow capture that the message was in fact sent. So for example, say I sent an email to a user today, then tomorrow comes around and Im ready to run the script I dont want the same exact email going out again to that same user (unless something has changed... like a new customer was added for that user  )

Comment: When you send the message, update the database to record that time. Then the query that looks for customers to send to can use `WHERE last_sent < DATETIME('now' '-1 day')`

Comment: @Barmar I like that idea, but I should have prefaced that I dont have the power to update tables, only read from them. We depend on another department to manipulate our tables unfortunately!

Comment: This should be automated as part of the application that sends the emails, not done by individuals in departments.

Comment: If you can't save when the emails were sent, then there's obviously no way to do what you want.

Comment: Are you using a third-party email service, like Twilio SendGrid? They may have an API that allows you to get this information.

Comment: Yeah I know its silly!  We are using MS Outlook and ive used smtplib to generate the email.   that would be nice if I could get a sort of sent "receipt" I wonder if  smtplib has a way to grab that info?

Comment: Where would smtplib save it if you're not able to update the database?

Comment: Where do you run this code? Why don't you simply create a text file (by date as its name, for example) on the local drive where this is running, and write the details into it. Everyday, open the file from previous day, and don;t send emails if the entry is already in there. Add a section to delete old files.

Comment: @userMT yes thats what I was thinking! if a user was sent an email yesterday - give it a 1 or something, if not leave it 0 and build that into the logic

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you don't need to know when the email was sent successfully, you need to know when your email was correctly received.

They look similar, but they are different.

The Offen marketing campaign uses this approach, because for them:

- OK = user opened the email
- KO = all other situations (SPAM, not
  open,....)

If you need something like this, I propose you solve it at the application level (as other solutions work). Like?

1. You can put the image, hosted on some server, in the email.
2. When the user opens their email this image will be loaded.
3. On your server you can configure a trigger (to be executed when this
   URL is called) to do some UPDATE on the database to ensure the user
   has opened their email.

**PS:**
I use an image as an example, but you can use anything else.

**PS:**
Admittedly, this URL must be unique per user (URL or query string)